Are President Kirari and her assistant, Sayaka, together?
Are Kirari and Sayaka officially together? I ask this because when Yumeko and Sayaka play the Tower of Doors, Sayaka loses and, as a rule, jumps off the 5th-story door. Then we see Kirari jump after Sayaka and she licks some blood off of Sayaka's head. They also hold hands. So are they a couple or not?(The image is after the jump)
